# sum up an array of object type

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to sum up an array that includes two different types of arrays.

Here is my method and the two different types of the arrays that I am trying to sum up :

```
public void test3() {
    // ArrayList tickets declaration required here
    ArrayList<Object> tickets = new ArrayList<Object>();

    tickets.add(new SeasonTicket(10.50, 30));
    tickets.add(new SeasonTicket(21.0, 30));
    tickets.add(new FirstClassSeason(10.50, 30, 10.50));
    tickets.add(new FirstClassSeason(21.0, 30, 21.0));

    double total = 0.0;

    for (int i=0; i< tickets.size(); i++)
    {
      total += tickets.get(i);      
    }
    ...
}
```

When I try to run the method i have the followin error : "The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Object". Do anyone know how to solve that error?

**Found the solution ,I should include
"

```
for (int i=0; i< tickets.size(); i++)
{
    total += ((SeasonTicket) tickets.get(i)).getCost();     
}
```

"
Thank you!

Comment: Add the code for `SeasonTicket` and `FirstClassSeason` as well, also what you wanted to sum up as there are 2 double values

Comment: Ask yourself (ignoring the fact this is a Java problem, briefly): what does 0 + ticket mean, logically?

Comment: is every `FirstClassSeason` inherit from `SeasonTicket`?

Comment: "Found the solution ,I should include" sort of. A better solution is to define `ArrayList<Season nTicket>`, then you don't need the cast.

Comment: @javaguy there is nothing wrong with posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

> "The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) double, Object"

Yes,that is correct, you cant just do that operation directly, when you do

```
 tickets.get(i);
```

you are getting the object in the list, so you can not do math operations with that

you need to call a method of that object instead, and the return of that value will be appended to the **total** var

```
total += tickets.get(i).getSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add objects. This doesn't make any sense. I think you want to sum up the prices of the ticket, like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tickets.size(); i++)
{
    total += tickets.get(i).getPrice();      
}
```